# Parallelizing creating list of lists using multiprocessor

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, multiprocessor

I am creating a list of lists using a function that takes a long time to calculate each of the list elements. Since this is slowing down my whole process, I'm trying to make it run faster by using the `multiprocessing` library in python.

However, When I try to use the multiprocessor, it makes my code run even slower. Any idea why this is happening?

```
import multiprocessing
import time

# arbitrary F function for a reproducible example
# The actual function is more complicated
def f(a, b):
    for i in range(100000):
        a = True
    return [a * b, a + b]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    G = [1, 2]
    l = [t for t in range(6000)]

    t1 = time.time()
    my_list1 = [[f(l[x], G[i])[0] for i in range(len(G))] for x in range(len(l))]
    t2 = time.time()
    print("Original: ", t2 - t1)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    t3 = time.time()
    my_list2 = [[pool.apply(f, args=(l[x], G[i]))[0] for i in range(len(G))] for x in range(len(l))]
    t4 = time.time()
    pool.close()
    print("Parallelized: ", t4 - t3)
```

example Output:

```
Original:  29.832287073135376
Parallelized:  33.75640296936035
```

Any notes on how I can create this list in parallel are appreciated.

Comment: `pool.apply` does not run asynchronously, it blocks until the result is ready. You should use one of the async variants and then construct the result when they are all done

Comment: starting multiple processes eats time

Comment: As already commented, your execution is still sequential. apply_async is the non-blocking version of apply but then your syntax changes. 

Your extra slowness is mostly caused by your return objects being huge. Multiprocessing handles data in/data out as queues and they are slow. When you return a huge array, this will take time. 

Either accept the time it takes without multiprocessing,  or re-engineer your code so that it does everything it needs to do in subprocesses so that you don't need to transmit so much data between processes.